# Getting all months in an Year from Entity Framework core query

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have done following `EF.core(3.1/3.2)` query

```
var monthlySalesList = context.Bids.Include(r => r.AllRequest).ThenInclude(r => r.Category).Where(b => b.UID== UID && (b.Status == MyStatus.Awarded || b.Status == MyStatus.Completed))
                    .GroupBy(a => new { Month =a.InsertedDate.Month })

                  .Select(g => new MyServiceList()
                  {
                      Key = g.Key.ToString(),
                      Month = g.Key.Month.ToString(),
                      Total= g.Sum(s => s.totalBudget)

                  }).ToList();
```

I am not getting all months in an year instead it displays only 2 months say ( 10,11) with total.In above query Mystatus is an `ENUM` class and `MyserviceList Model` class contains get & set such as `key,month,sum and total` .

I am getting only

```
-----------------
Months total
------------------
10   1234
11  1212
```

How can I get remaining months with zero value.

```
-----------------
Months total
------------------
1    0 
2    0
3    0
4    0
5    0
6    0
7    0
8    0
9    0
10   1234
11  1212
12  0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Define another list
2. Make a for loop after "monthlySalesList" and make query from the list.
3. if you did not get data,  set 0 on new list, otherwise set value .

for example :

Class :
public class ReportData
{
public int month { get; set; }
public int total { get; set; }
}

Code :

List reportData = new List();

```
        for (int i = 1; i <= 12; i++)
        {
            try
            {
                Bids bids = new Bids();

                bids = monthlySalesList.Where(t => t.month == i).FirstOrDefault();


                if(bids == null)
                {
                    reportData.Add(new ReportData() {
                    month = i,
                    total = 0
                    });
                }
                else
                {
                    reportData.Add(new ReportData()
                    {
                        month = i,
                        total = bids.total
                    });
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {

            }


        }
```

Comment: it doesn't work . seems    total = bids.Month wrong

Comment: it works now I have done some modification. I have accepted